# How to destructure an object without one key

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, destructuring

I have an object like `obj = { test1: 'sth', test2: 'sth', label: 'sth' }`.

And I would like to destructure this object `{...obj}` *except* `label` to get `{ test1: 'sth', test2: 'sth' }`.

How to destructure the object without this key?

Should I create a new object or is there any way to do this simply in one line?

Comment: *Destructuring* is something different than *destruction*.

Comment: readability would suggest to simply copy the properties you want, it would be more clear from a reviewers stand point that's intended :)

Comment: You can do the following:

`const {label, ...exceptLabel} = obj;`

Comment: @ChauTran worked! thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple delete should do the trick.

```
delete obj.label;
```

EDIT: apparently my question did not do destructuring properly.  Perhaps something like the following would work then.

```
({label, ...rest} = {test1: 'sth', test2: 'sth', label: 'sth' });
console.debug(rest);
```

Rest should contain only test1 and test2 properties/values.

Comment: Based on the question, it seemed the person asking simply wanted to remove the single property from an object.  Communication is key, I would ask why they want to destructure in the first place when something simpler would do.